# Cycle through a list of letters in multiple groups

Tags: replace, list, vimscript-lua

So I have a case where I have some unicode letters say `[B, Ḅ, Ḃ]` and when I have my mouse selected over the B, (in normal mode) I want some way of cycling through the list. Like pressing some command should replace `B` with `Ḅ`, pressing it again should replace `Ḅ` with `Ḃ`.

---

I looked at this https://github.com/zef/vim-cycle/blob/master/plugin/cycle.vim, but it was not quite what I was looking for as

1. It works on words not letters
2. I sometimes need multiple groups

---

Say this is group associated with hotkey A `[$ Ɗ Ʋ]`
I also need a second group B, with a second hotkey which would cycle `[$ ¥]`, `[Ɗ ɗ]` and `[Ʋ ʋ]`.

Finally (and I might ask this in a follow up question), very rarely I would need to do a two group cycle. Something like `[Ð¡, Ð¿, Ðḟ, ...]` Which would always start with a `Ð`. Any ideas, or resources to look for?

I tagged this with vimscript Lua, simply because I am open to solving this issue with Lua if it makes it easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution thanks to [How to add accent to letters in normal mode?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/12988/how-to-add-accent-to-letters-in-normal-mode?rq=1) using `tr`. As stated in the comments a simple 3 cycle would be done by

```
tr(@", 'ABC', 'BCA')
```

Which cycles `A -> B -> C -> A`. Wrapped in a command it looks like

```
nnoremap <silent> <localleader>ln s<c-r>=tr(@", 'ABC', 'BCA')
```

However, this gets a bit nasty when trying to add several cycles into the same command as in my real example beneath

```
nnoremap <silent> <localleader>ln s<c-r>=tr(@", '3456789³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹AẠȦÄBḄḂƁCÇĊƇDÐḌḊƊEẸĖ', '³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹3456789ẠȦÄAḄḂƁBÇĊƇCÐḌḊƊDẸĖE')<cr><esc>
" nnoremap <silent> <localleader>lp s<c-r>=tr(@", 'ABC', 'BCA')<cr><esc>

nnoremap <silent> <localleader>lq s<c-r>=tr(@", '©ß¢ÇçÑñ£Ŀŀ¦¡¿/ƒ\¤$ƊƲ¥ɗʋ#?Ƒ⁺@`"þ{}€ÞƝƤƙɼƭⱮƇƬ', 'ß¢ÇçÑñ£Ŀŀ¦¡¿/ƒ\¤$ƊƲ¥ɗʋ#?Ƒ⁺@`"þ{}€ÞƝƤƙɼƭⱮƇƬ©')<cr><esc>
" nnoremap <silent> <localleader>la s<c-r>=tr(@", 'ABC', 'BCA')<cr><esc>
```

Do note that everything works, but I will be asking a separate follow up question on how to make the formatting more bearable, because this will turn into a nightmare debugging,  =)

<sup>and I have only added A-E still got D-Z...</sup>

Answer (score 2):

At least for single characters, here's what I would do. First, let's build a little function for an expression map. It takes a dictionary corresponding to the cycle, examines the character under the cursor, and returns the sequence of commands to do. This is either a `r` command or nothing.

```
function CyclePair(which_pairs) abort
  let char_under_cursor = strpart(getline('.'), col('.') - 1, 1, v:true)
  return has_key(a:which_pairs, char_under_cursor)
        \ ? 'r'.a:which_pairs[char_under_cursor]
        \ : ''
endfunction
```

Then we can map it like

```
nnoremap <expr> <leader>r CyclePair({'a': 'b', 'b': 'c', 'c': 'a'})
" ... more mappings, different pairs, no big deal.
```

Typing the dictionary is a slight pain and easy to get wrong. It would be nicer to just use a list.

```
function MakePairs(xs) abort
  let len = len(a:xs)
  return range(len)->reduce({ acc, val -> extend(acc, {a:xs[val]: a:xs[(val+1)%len]}) }, {})
endfunction
```

So now we can write

```
nnoremap <expr> <leader>r CyclePair(MakePairs(['a', 'b', 'c']))
```

Comment: With this approach would I need a different keybinding for each cycle pair? I think I have 26 or so in total (in group A), so I feel like it might be better if it were `CyclePairs` instead. Alas, it seems inefficient having to look through 26 groups to see if the char is in one of them. With that being said, this seems like a great start!

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar ah, i did forget about that. Part of the issue is there is overlap between cycles, so that may be non-trivial. But dictionary could have multiple unrelated cycles in it (a to b to c and d to e to f).

Comment: I might be on to something with `tr`. E.g `tr(@", 'ABC', 'BCA')` would perform a simple 3 cycle. I'll look into it today and might answer my own question if it works out =)

Comment: Ah, I forgot about tr. That might make some of the code more bearable.