# Cycle through a list of letters in multiple groups - Code review

Tags: vimscript, replace, list

This is a follow up question to [Cycle through a list of letters in multiple groups](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/31779/cycle-through-a-list-of-letters-in-multiple-groups) where I asked how to cycle a group of letters. I got a bunch of great tips and this is my follow up question.

**This is simply asking for a code review of my attempt at solving this problem**

---

##### Explanation

My code simply allows the user to hit some key combination (temporarily set to `<localleader>ln` and `<localleader>lp`) to replace the letter under the cursor with the next letter in the cycle.

---

Here are some of my thoughts on the current state of my code.

My script flashes the contents of the `tr` command upon execution to the statusline. I tried to avoid this by using `!` (silent) without much success.

I tried to make sure I do not mess with the user's registers, however, this solution seems unnecessarily verbose. Any suggestions for improvements here are more than welcome.

`s\<c-r>=tr(@\",'" . a:letters . "','" . a:replacements . "')\<cr>\<esc>`" executes a command in normal mode, then *immediately* go to insert mode using `s`. Then it switches to invoking an (Ex?) command using `<C-r>=`. Is this really the best way to replace the letter under my cursor by invoking `tr` over it? It feels as my code jumps between two many modes.

Initially I had some issues with my code, I tried `tr(@\"," . a:letters . "," . a:replacements . ")` without much success. I had to add `'` around the variables to make it work, why? I thought they already were stored as strings?

Can this code be written cleaner/better? This is the first time I've ever written a function in vimscript. I do not know about any style guides, nor how to lint my code. I choose to do this with vimscript, and I'm not really sure why I did that over lua. Alternative approaches are welcome.

#### Code

```
function! TryReplaceLetters(letters, replacements)
    let save_cb = &cb
    let regText = getreg('"', 1, 1)
    try
        execute "normal! s\<c-r>=tr(@\",'" . a:letters . "','" . a:replacements . "')\<cr>\<esc>"
    finally
        let &cb = save_cb
        call setreg('"', regText)
    endtry
endfunction 

let s:lookalikes = "1¹2²3³4⁴5⁵6⁶7⁶8⁸9⁹AẠȦÄÆBḄḂƁßCÇĊƇ©DÐḌḊƊEẸĖ£ÆŒFḞƑGĠƓHḤḢIỊİJȷKḲLḶĿMṂṀⱮNṆṄÑƝOȮØŒPṖƤQỌRṚṘ®SṢṠTṬṪƬUỤƲVṾWẈẆXẊYỴẎ¥ZẒŻaạȧæbḅḃþcċç¢dḍḋɗeẹæœfḟƒgḥḣiị¡jkƙlḷŀmṃṁnñoọȯøœpṗÞrṛṙɼsṣṡ$tṭṫƭvʋwẇxẋyżz"
let s:lookcycles = "¹1²2³3⁴4⁵5⁶6⁶7⁸8⁹9ÆAẠȦÄßBḄḂƁ©CÇĊƇƊDÐḌḊŒEẸĖ£ÆƑFḞƓGĠḢHḤİIỊȷJḲKĿLḶⱮMṂṀƝNṆṄÑŒOȮØƤPṖỌQ®RṚṘṠSṢƬTṬṪƲUỤṾVẆWẈẊX¥YỴẎŻZẒæaạȧþbḅḃ¢cċçɗdḍḋœeẹæƒfḟgḣḥ¡iịjƙkŀlḷṁmṃñnœoọȯøÞpṗɼrṛṙ$sṣṡƭtṭṫʋvẇwẋxżyz"

function! JellyLookaLikes()
    " Cycles through similar looking symbols, clockwise
    return TryReplaceLetters(s:lookalikes, s:lookcycles)
endfunction 

function! JellyLookaLikesPrev()
    " Cycles through similar looking symbols, counter-clockwise
    return TryReplaceLetters(s:lookcycles, s:lookalikes)
endfunction 

nnoremap <silent> <localleader>ln :call JellyLookaLikes()<cr><esc>
nnoremap <silent> <localleader>lp :call JellyLookaLikesPrev()<cr><esc>
```

Comment: Please try to stick to one main question per question. A code review is a valid question, though, and I can point out a few things.

Comment: As far as I know, there's no style guides. I've read a lot of code in vimscript, and what I've concluded style-wise is that no one really agrees on a best-practice (... beyond stuff enforced by Vim :p). Use whatever you feel comfortable with, or whatever makes sense to you, and whatever you feel makes sense for your project.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble How would a better approach been? I accepted my last question as it answered my question about cycling letters. This, as you say is more of a code review. I can update the title with that. I was under the impression that a Q&A site preferred one question per question. The bullet points are just my thoughts about the code I wrote / what it would be _nice_ to have addressed in  a code review =)

Comment: Bullets are fine, you just seemed to be asking many qs. As a code review, we can address those bullets as part of a larger review

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Style

- You spell out functions/commands/&c., which I think is wonderful. But you
  didn't spell out `&cb`. Prefer `&clipboard`.
- It appears you mixed spaces and tabs. Prefer one or the other (I use 2 spaces
  for vimscript).
- You're missing `abort` on your functions.
- `function!` is not strictly necessary according to `:help E127`, but this
  changed—I believe its prevalence is mostly a historical artifact at this
  point.

Otherwise, stylistically this looks pretty solid. The only other thing I can
think of is to use `const` if you have a new enough vim, and I think `execute printf("…", …)` looks nicer than string concatenation.

## Code

- The duplication in `s:lookalikes` and `s:lookcycles` is somewhat troublesome.
  I would prefer to find a way to write the pairs down once and then
  programmatically derive the required parts.
- You save and restore the `clipboard` option, but don't change it. Perhaps you
  meant to include `set clipboard&`?
- The `clipboard` option is only available "`in GUI versions or when the |+xterm_clipboard| is included`"—you should test for those if you use it.
- For registers, you should use `getreginfo()`—it saves more information
  correctly, and the result can be given directly to `setreg()`.
- As written, the quoting nastiness is necessary: `tr` needs string arguments.
  If you wrote, for example,

  ```
  let source = 'bcd'
  let target = 'abc'
  let a = tr('b', source, target)
  ```

  then everything is fine. But you're inside an `execute` concatenating
  strings. Try

  ```
  :echo "tr(@\",'" . source . "','" . target . "')"
  ```

  to see the
  command you're building—notice the strings have been concatenated, so the fact
  that they were string variables isn't seen in the final command. I get

  ```
  tr(@",'bcd','abc')
  ```

  Without the quotes, the command would look for variables `bcd` and `abc`.

  But we can avoid jumping through all these hoops. Let's use a simple command
  to grab the character under the cursor. `:normal! yl` will do, if you like the
  register stuff. `:help strpart()` suggests

  ```
  strpart(getline('.'), col('.') - 1, 1, v:true)
  ```

  to get the character under the cursor (but this might fail for multi-byte
  characters, such as emoji).

  Either way, we get the character in a variable we can manipulate normally, and
  then finally do an `:execute ':normal! r'.replacement`.

Putting it altogether, I would write something like below. I've left the letters
alone because, to be honest, it was very difficult to read.

```
function TryReplaceLetters(letters, replacements) abort
  if has('gui') || has('xterm_clipboard')
    let save_cb = &clipboard
    set clipboard&
  endif
  let save_reg = getreginfo('"')
  try
    normal! yl
    let char_to_change = @"
  finally
    if has('gui') || has('xterm_clipboard')
      let &clipboard = save_cb
    endif
    call setreg('"', save_reg)
  endtry
  let replacement = tr(char_to_change, a:letters, a:replacements)
  " avoid changes if same character
  if replacement isnot# char_to_change
    execute ':normal! r'.replacement
  endif
endfunction

let s:lookalikes = "1¹2²3³4⁴5⁵6⁶7⁶8⁸9⁹AẠȦÄÆBḄḂƁßCÇĊƇ©DÐḌḊƊEẸĖ£ÆŒFḞƑGĠƓHḤḢIỊİJȷKḲLḶĿMṂṀⱮNṆṄÑƝOȮØŒPṖƤQỌRṚṘ®SṢṠTṬṪƬUỤƲVṾWẈẆXẊYỴẎ¥ZẒŻaạȧæbḅḃþcċç¢dḍḋɗeẹæœfḟƒgḥḣiị¡jkƙlḷŀmṃṁnñoọȯøœpṗÞrṛṙɼsṣṡ$tṭṫƭvʋwẇxẋyżz"
let s:lookcycles = "¹1²2³3⁴4⁵5⁶6⁶7⁸8⁹9ÆAẠȦÄßBḄḂƁ©CÇĊƇƊDÐḌḊŒEẸĖ£ÆƑFḞƓGĠḢHḤİIỊȷJḲKĿLḶⱮMṂṀƝNṆṄÑŒOȮØƤPṖỌQ®RṚṘṠSṢƬTṬṪƲUỤṾVẆWẈẊX¥YỴẎŻZẒæaạȧþbḅḃ¢cċçɗdḍḋœeẹæƒfḟgḣḥ¡iịjƙkŀlḷṁmṃñnœoọȯøÞpṗɼrṛṙ$sṣṡƭtṭṫʋvẇwẋxżyz"

function JellyLookaLikes() abort
  " Cycles through similar looking symbols, clockwise
  return TryReplaceLetters(s:lookalikes, s:lookcycles)
endfunction

function JellyLookaLikesPrev() abort
  " Cycles through similar looking symbols, counter-clockwise
  return TryReplaceLetters(s:lookcycles, s:lookalikes)
endfunction

nnoremap <silent> <localleader>ln :call JellyLookaLikes()<cr><esc>
nnoremap <silent> <localleader>lp :call JellyLookaLikesPrev()<cr><esc>
```

Here's an example of turning a list of cycles into the two arguments necessary:
assume each cycle is a list of characters, and cycles is a list of cycles.

```
function ToTrArgs(cycles) abort
  let first_argument = deepcopy(a:cycles)->flatten()->join('')
  let second_argument = mapnew(a:cycles, {_, v -> [v[-1]]+v[:-2]})->flatten()->join('')
  return [first_argument, second_argument]
endfunction

let [s:forwards, s:backwards] = ToTrArgs([['a','á','à'], ['b', 'ḃ']])

function JellyLookaLikes()
  " Cycles through similar looking symbols, clockwise
  return TryReplaceLetters(s:forwards, s:backwards)
endfunction

function JellyLookaLikesPrev()
  " Cycles through similar looking symbols, counter-clockwise
  return TryReplaceLetters(s:backwards, s:forwards)
endfunction

nnoremap <silent> <localleader>ln :call JellyLookaLikes()<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <localleader>lp :call JellyLookaLikesPrev()<CR>
" alternatively, if you don't like the whole "s:var not valid in mapping" thing,
" use call() with a list argument
nnoremap <silent> <localleader>ln :call call('TryReplaceLetters', ToTrArgs([['a','á','à'], ['b', 'ḃ']]))<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <localleader>lp :call call('TryReplaceLetters', ToTrArgs([['a','á','à'], ['b', 'ḃ']])->reverse())<CR>
```

Comment: fantastic review! I will read it throughly when I have time. Just to make sure as long as I am _only_ working on the `@` register I do not need any of the code related to the clipboard right? I just wanted to make sure I do not mess up anything. I was unsure of my uses of `l:`, `a:` to narrow the scope of my functions, and I see you do not use these either. Are these also a relic form the past? And again thanks a bunch

Comment: Honestly I’m not sure if clipboard needs modified. It might. I don’t use l: anymore inside functions, but I use a: (mandatory), s:, g:, w:, t:, b:, etc.